# Corsair Vengeance 2100 on OS X

Tags: hardware

I just purchased the Crosair Vengeance 2100 headset to use with Steam on OS X (Mountain Lion) and to use with Skype.

I can get the headset to be detected by OS X and set it up as a sound device but after a few minutes the audio and mic cut out with the only way to reset it is to pull the USB adapter out and put it back in (and then go reset the output devices in OS X).

Has anyone been able to get it to properly work on OS X?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the sound only cut out in game, or does it happen no matter what you're doing on the computer?

Comment: This happens in game (Steam) and just listening to music (iTunes).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using it wireless or plugged in?

If you are wireless, I'll bet they're low on charge. If you look where the cord connects, it's likely blinking or solid red (which means you need to charge them).

As for the adapter, you don't need to keep un-plugging to reset them. On the left ear, you press the button for a few seconds. This will re-sync the headset to your USB adapter. If it correctly sync'ed, the blinking blue light on the adapter will stop blinking on stay solid.